# Mandarin equivalent for 返嚟?

Tags: grammar, cantonese

In Cantonese 返嚟 is often used when asking someone about where they obtained something from. For instance, "學返嚟“ could be used in a sentence asking someone, "Where did you learn this from?"

What's the Mandarin equivalent for 返嚟 in this context?

Answer (score 1):

The most usual verbal suffix is just 來/来 *lái*. This can be combined with 著/着 *zhe* after it. See Definition 7 [here](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%9D%A5):

> 7 用在动词后，表示做过（一般均可用“来着”）：昨天他哭～。

The use of 来着 is very frequent in northern colloquial Mandarin, but is a more general past tense marker with some sense of "just now", with [an idea of a continuous state](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IGDiCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT119) according to some analyses. It is a very well researched construction in academic studies of Mandarin.

The most common equivalent for Cantonese [返嚟](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/5203/) is Mandarin [回來/来 *huílai*](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/10287/), but this is more restricted in usage as a verbal suffix, and has a stronger connotation of "coming back home" (e.g. buying something back, receiving something back as a ransom), which is not required in this sentence.